# Linux: Visual diff for two git commits -- entire repo

Tags: linux, git, user-interface, directory, diff

There are many questions on stackoverflow that are similar to this question. Most discuss single files, diff files, or filenames. Very few discus **GUIs for viewing the diff of two hashes for an entire git repository** (ALL directories, subdirectories, and files). The one or two comments I've seen mention tools only available on Windows (like araxis merge) or OS/X.

What about linux? Meld is my preferred tool so I've tried:

```
git show <hash1> <hash2> > /tmp/clownshoes.diff
```

then opened that in meld. No luck. Meld sees it as one single giant.

Comment: You probably want to use `git diff`, not `git show`.

Comment: Once again, meld simply opens that as a text file. It's not recognizing it as a diff file for me.

Comment: Why are you creating a text file in the first place? Can't you do something like `git difftool -t meld <hash1> <hash2>`?

Comment: When I do that, meld displays a single file on the right side, all in green. The left side contains nothing.

Comment: Perhaps there's some strange case with the two commits you are inspecting. The `difftool` command works for me on Linux with Meld. (I forgot to include the `-d` flag before, which is helpful.) Can you try with some other commits? Also, which version of Git are you using?

Comment: Try git diffall, it opens up a directory tree in your difftool of choice

Comment: @Chris, I'm using git 1.7.9.5. I'

Comment: @Chris, I've tried `-d` in various places on the cmd line but git doesn't like it. Suggestions? @Andrew: git: 'diffall' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at git's list of [gui clients](http://git-scm.com/download/gui/linux), I think smart git will do what you are looking for.

Comment: Which one of the GUI clients provide a visual diff ?

Comment: [Smartgit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/) is able to show the difference between two branches from what I understand.

Comment: I installed Smartgit, poked around and yes, it does what I need. Click the "Log" button in the toolbar. A new window opens. Highlight two commit hashes in the new window. You'll see the list of directories and files on the Details box on the right. The bottom half of the window shows a visual diff. Thanks, @Eadword. I don't know who downvoted you, but it wasn't me!